# Как в список добавить элементы другого списка?

Tags: python

Всем добрый день. Есть 2 списка. Как можно в один список засунуть другой список, но только по одному элементу?

```
sp_with_follow = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
res_list = ['1', 2, '3', 4, 5]
for i in range(len(sp_with_follow)):
    for cv in sp_with_follow:
        res_list.insert(4, cv)

print(res_list)
```

Вывод:

```
['1', 2, '3', 4, 'five', 'four', 'three', 'two', 'one', 'five', 'four', 'three', 'two', 'one', 'five', 'four', 'three', 'two', 'one', 'five', 'four', 'three', 'two', 'one', 'five', 'four', 'three', 'two', 'one', 5]
```

Но как на выходе получить

```
['1', 2, '3', 4, 'one', 5, '1', 2, '3', 4, 'two', 5, '1', 2, '3', 4, 'three', 5, '1', 2, '3', 4, 'four', 5, '1', 2, '3', 4, 'five', 5]
```

Comment: По моему кто-то задачки самостоятельно решать не хочет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138350/Как-в-список-добавить-элементы-другого-списка-с-индексом-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
a = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
b = ['1', 2, '3', 4, 5]


def very_strange_combine(a, b):
    res_list = []

    for i in a:
        for j in b:
            res_list.append(j)
        res_list.append(i)    

    return res_list

print(very_strange_combine(a, b))
```

Comment: `sum(([*b, e] for e in a), [])`)))