# Как в список добавить элементы другого списка с индексом 4?

Tags: python

Всем добрый день. Есть 2 списка. Как можно в один список засунуть другой список, но только по одному элементу?

```
sp_with_follow = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
res_list = ['1', 2, '3', 4, 5]
for i in range(len(sp_with_follow)):
    for cv in sp_with_follow:
        res_list.insert(4, cv)

print(res_list)
```

Вывод:

```
['1', 2, '3', 4, 'five', 'four', 'three', 'two', 'one', 'five', 'four', 'three', 'two', 'one', 'five', 'four', 'three', 'two', 'one', 'five', 'four', 'three', 'two', 'one', 'five', 'four', 'three', 'two', 'one', 5]
```

Но как на выходе получить

```
['1', 2, '3', 4, 'one', 5, '1', 2, '3', 4, 'two', 5, '1', 2, '3', 4, 'three', 5, '1', 2, '3', 4, 'four', 5, '1', 2, '3', 4, 'five', 5]
```

**Слова one, two и т.д. должны стоять до пятерки, индекс 4**

Comment: изменяя смысл вопроса, на который вам уже дали ответы, вы инвалидируете данные вам ответы

Comment: В самом деле, не делайте так больше. Вы молодец конечно, что хорошо оформили вопрос, только все отвечали на другой, который заключался совсем в другом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sp_with_follow = ['479728', '2302', '5578', '2794', '39', '39', '153', '24', '772', '71']

res_list = [10, 'Коронавирус в России: оперативная информация', 'Сообщения информационных агентств о коронавирусе в России.', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2Fd68d12f0-68e2-4c62-9337-4d733f1b10ac', '08.06.2020', 1197, 2827003, 0, 
9, 'Sport24', 'Проектsport24.ru— новый взгляд на мир спорта и всё, что его окружает.', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2F100366dc-d55f-4169-bc51-f3c36545aaf2', '08.06.2020', 607, 691, 0,
8, 'Афиша', 'Городской интернет-журнал о культурном досуге.', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2F64046f2c-bb82-4f71-8501-117cd2668cc0', '08.06.2020', 1392, 2884, 0, 
7, '«Собака.ru»', 'Журнал о людях, культуре, моде, трендах в Петербурге', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2Fd06d1586-2721-4478-886f-96d7b0060c9b', '08.06.2020', 769, 735, 0,
6, 'iHealth  |  Здоровье и здоровый образ жизни', 'Самый полезный блог о здоровье', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2Fd0f9d3ec-8929-49e4-8d35-001e188a9069', '08.06.2020', 614, 73, 0, 
5, 'Продуктовые каталоги в Москве', 'Смотрите новые каталоги Пятерочка, Дикси, Перекресток, Магнит, Билла, Лента, ОКЕЙ, Верный, Виктория, Карусель, Eurospar, МЕТРО. Только свежые акции от супермаркетов Москвы.', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2Fbc16eb47-e11b-4335-91b9-2d041ebf0514', '08.06.2020', 608, 196, 0, 
4, 'Шутки по 300', 'Нам юмор работать и жить помогает', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2F73db1cdf-546f-4b55-87a3-6f99d7932ad1', '08.06.2020', 529, 271, 0, 
3, 'Apple Blog', 'Про гаджеты и технологии', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2F2c5a7b9e-e9f1-4732-bb86-df4da83bf42c', '08.06.2020', 1298, 62, 0, 
2, 'Коронавирус РФ', 'Все честные новости в одном месте.Знай что происходит сегодня!', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2F356f248c-7529-45dd-aeef-c3535ed03325', '08.06.2020', 1073, 690, 0, 
1, 'Советы Сценаристу', 'Полезные советы для тех, кто пишет.', 'https://yandex.ru/chat/#/chats/1%2F0%2F203d5cd7-d844-4498-9c04-e9079126bdf6', '08.06.2020', 2202, 2374, 0]


result=list()
for res in res_list:

    """ Добавляем элемент в результат:
    """
    result.append(res)

    if isinstance(res, str) and res.startswith("http"):

        """ В упрощенном варианте принимаем элемент ссылкой.

            После ссылки добавляем число:
        """
        try:

            result.append(sp_with_follow.pop(0))

        except:

            """ Недостаточно чисел в sp_with_follow.
                В нашем случае просто игнорируем их.
            """
            print("Not enought values in sp_with_follow. Continue..")

            pass

print(result)
```